# Adding Custom CloudWatch dashboard to Application Insights using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

On AWS Application Insights, I am able to import custom cloudwatch dashboard through the management console.

[Custom CloudWatch dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upuvY.png)

I am not seeing an option to import through cloud formation in the documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationinsights-application.html

Is there a way to do this through cloud formation so that it is not done manually?

I tried exploring the documentation but was not able to see anything relating to Custom CloudWatch dashboard.